# Sharepoint 2013 - can't use quick view with newsletter style document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, quick-edit

I notice I lose the function of the quick edit if I customize my view to use something like the newsletter style. Is there a way around this - keeping the view and still maintaining quick view editing?

Answer (score 2):

The "quick edit" option edit all your rows and columns in the current view. There are events triggers on leaving each row. 
So this feature supports only in Default style and other style formats won`t support.

Comment: Thanks - I decided to use tow displays - one for editing and one for main display.